# RegEx for matching various dates

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to put together a regex statement to match on each of the below date formats.

```
* Mar 7, 2017
Mar. 7, 2017
* March 7, 2017
3-7-2017
03-07-2017
3-7-17
03-07-17
* 03/7/2017
* 03/07/17
* 3/7/17
Mar-07-2017
Mar-7-2017
March-07-2017
```

The below regex matches on the date formats that are indicated by an asterisk above. I have tried in vain to add to what I already have but have been unsuccessful.

> ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|\w+\s\d{2},\s\d{4}|(?i)\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec](?:ember)?)\b
>   (?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]),? \d{4}

Any help is always appreciated!

*** Bonus question ***

On some occasions, there may be multiple date matches and I need it to find a match following a certain word. In the past I've used the below syntax by enclosing the regex statement between the parenthesis after the period.

```
(?<=Word).(StatementHere)
```

Comment: What about the (standard) date format 7/3/2017? You're excluding the majority of the world if you don't also accept D / M / Y.

Comment: While that may be true, I only need it to match in the formats I listed. If there is a statement that can cover the format you listed, I will gladly accept that as well :). It just isn't required for my need.

Comment: Are you using PCRE (php),  or Perl or Ruby ?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that as I don't necessarily use any of those. I copy the content into Notepad++ and then use the "Find" and set the search mode to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: Notepad++ uses PCRE, but it doesn't matter. I was just going to optimize the regex with some functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then ...

```
([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(\d{4}|\d{2}))|\w+\s\d{2},\s\d{4}|(?i)\b(Jan(?:uary|\.)?|Feb(?:ruary|\.)?|Mar(?:ch|\.)?|Apr(?:il|\.)?|May|Jun(?:e|\.)?|Jul(?:y|\.)?|Aug(?:ust|\.)?|Sep(?:tember|\.)?|Oct(?:ober|\.)?|Nov(?:ember|\.)?|Dec(?:ember|\.)?)([ ](?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]),?[ ]|-(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])-)(\d{4})
```

https://regex101.com/r/k1vaVN/1

[Readable version](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
    ( [0-9]+ )                    # (1)
    /
    ( [0-9]+ )                    # (2)
    /
    ( [0-9]+ )                    # (3)
 |  
    (                             # (4 start)
         ( 0? [1-9] | 1 [0-2] )        # (5)
         -
         ( 0? [1-9] | [12] \d | 3 [01] )  # (6)
         -
         ( \d{4} | \d{2} )             # (7)
    )                             # (4 end)
 |  
    \w+ \s \d{2} , \s \d{4} 
 |  
    (?i)
    \b 
    (                             # (8 start)
         Jan
         (?: uary | \. )?
      |  Feb
         (?: ruary | \. )?
      |  Mar
         (?: ch | \. )?
      |  Apr
         (?: il | \. )?
      |  May
      |  Jun
         (?: e | \. )?
      |  Jul
         (?: y | \. )?
      |  Aug
         (?: ust | \. )?
      |  Sep
         (?: tember | \. )?
      |  Oct
         (?: ober | \. )?
      |  Nov
         (?: ember | \. )?
      |  Dec
         (?: ember | \. )?
    )                             # (8 end)
    (                             # (9 start)
         [ ] 
         (?: 0? [1-9] | [1-2] [0-9] | 3 [01] )
         ,? [ ] 
      |  -
         (?: 0? [1-9] | [1-2] [0-9] | 3 [01] )
         -
    )                             # (9 end)
    ( \d{4} )                     # (10)
```

---

***update***
Just wrap the dates in a `(?: )` group, then add whatever qualifier before
it that you need.

```
word[ ]or[ ]phrase[ ]+\K(?:([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(\d{4}|\d{2}))|\w+\s\d{2},\s\d{4}|(?i)\b(Jan(?:uary|\.)?|Feb(?:ruary|\.)?|Mar(?:ch|\.)?|Apr(?:il|\.)?|May|Jun(?:e|\.)?|Jul(?:y|\.)?|Aug(?:ust|\.)?|Sep(?:tember|\.)?|Oct(?:ober|\.)?|Nov(?:ember|\.)?|Dec(?:ember|\.)?)([ ](?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]),?[ ]|-(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])-)(\d{4}))
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks for the detailed answer - by showing me each step. I also added an additional note to my original post. If there are multiple date matches, can I add something to get it to match directly following a specific word? (see addition to original post) The statement you provided works beautifully on it's own which I'll definitely use. But when I tried to nest it in my own existing statement it didn't return a match. Thanks again. Your a genius!

Comment: Cool! Ok, so I tried using.... MyWord+(?:YourSyntax) .... but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. That matches the word PLUS the date. I only want the match to return the date. Sorry for not clarifying better. Also, I think that there may be something wrong with the December part. It doesn't want to match on Dec. if followed by the period.

Comment: Ok, fixed the _December_ issue's and added the `\K` construct, to not match the preceding word, just the date. If your system doesn't do `\K`, use a lookbehind assertion that is fixed length, OR, put a capture group `()` around the date, then you can just reference group 1.

Comment: Both work great now! Thanks so much. I tried fixing the December issue by adding the missing characters but it didn't work. You have the magic touch.